# How to clear open connections in HPQC made by the ALM 12.5x REST API?

Tags: rest, http, alm, hp-quality-center, session-management

Currently I'm signing in to HPQC using this ALM REST endpoint:

```
POST /qcbin/api/authentication/sign-in
```

But when I hit these logout endpoints, my tokens/cookies becomes invalid which is good, BUT the connections made by my API requests do not get cleared in the HPQC open connections list:

```
GET /qcbin/authentication-point/logout
GET /qcbin/api/authentication/sign-out
DELETE /qcbin/rest/site-session
```

The HPQC instance I'm using has WAIT_BEFORE_DISCONNECT set to 2 minutes. After more than 2 minutes goes by, the connections remain open and my open connections just keep accumulating as I make more API requests.

Is there a way to clear a connection that gets opened due to an ALM REST API request using maybe a certain header or an additional api call since the logout/signout/clear site session endpoints only seem to invalidate tokens and don't actually close open connections?

Open connections list I'm referring to in HPQC:
[image]

Any help or insight would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You got to send a 'POST' request to `/logout` end-point

Comment: Question was answered here:

https://community.softwaregrp.com/t5/Quality-Center-ALM-User/How-to-clear-open-connections-in-HPQC-made-by-the-ALM-12-5x-REST/m-p/1653549#M98071